# Slicing String Values of different lengths and Assigning those Values to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, for-loop

I have multiple string values of differing lengths within a label, containing a checkbox, like so:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="standard-length">Course Title - Monday 9pm-12pm, $100
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="different-length">Different Length Title - Tuesday 12pm-2am, $200
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="everything">All - $400
</label>
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate through these strings, cut out the title, the time block, and the price, and store these in an object. First I had to .trim() the whitespace from the textContent of the label, and then I tried to use .split() and .slice() to get each segment of the string, but ran into a roadblock as the titles are of differing lengths, and there is one label that is missing the time altogether. The thought process was something like this:

```
let getStrDetails(str) => {
  const strDetails = {
    checkbox: '',
    title: '',
    day: '',
    time: '',
    price: ''
};
for (prop in strDetails) {
  // Check if the checkbox is checked, assign boolean true/false
  // Get the title and assign it to the title value in the object
  // Get the day and assign it to the day value in the object
  // Get the time...
  // Get the price, remove the $ and turn it into an integer for maths when calculating the totals (tried strDetails["price"] = str.slice(-3);

}
return str;
}
```

I assumed getting the price would be easy, they're all the same length at 3 digits and at the end of the string, so a .slice(-3) would work. But with the titles being different lengths, I was attempting to use the dash (" - ") as an ending index, and since each title starts with a space I tried to use that as well by accessing it with indexOf(1), since the first letter is technically after a space and the second character in the array. I then tried to use the "," as the end of an index as it falls after the time, etc.

I'm tying all of this to an event handler so the logic fires when the checkbox is clicked, as I'm also comparing conflicting days against one another and disabling the checkboxes if those fall on the same day and time.

I got this working using a completely different, albeit inelegant solution, but I'm trying to better understand how to assign values to and iterate through an object and creating accessible properties that I can use later, like so:

```
if(Get str1[time) and compare it to str2[time]) {
  // set str1 checkbox boolean to false and do something to disable it in the html
}
```

Comment: Yes, `indexOf(" - ")` or `lastIndexOf(",")` should do the job.

Comment: What strings exactly are you getting? If this runs in the browser, you should get the `.textContent` of the label and can ignore all the html stuff

Comment: I don't get why you are trying to loop the `strDetails` object. You should iterate the labels (lines), sure, but for each label you should just do assignments.

Comment: Because the segments of strings I'm trying to break up have a different number of words, I'm getting results which are cutting the strings at the wrong places. As for the object, I was attempting to store the different segments of the string in the object to access them later in another function, so I could, say, compare the values against one another, like: 
    `if(str1.day === str2.day) {str2.style.display = "none"}`